# Ethereum Wallet testnet not synching when mining

Tags: mining, wallets, synchronization, network

I am trying to mine on the testnet. Unfortunately, my Ethereum Wallet (latest version using Geth 1.5.3) kind of gives up doing anything when I click on start Mining on testnet. The time counts up is displayed in red, but nothing gets synchronized anymore.

In the "normal" non-mining mode, i've got up to 25 peers and actual blocks get synched from time to time (every ~20-40sec).

What could go wrong here? And how can I find out?

Comment: I can confirm the same for me. Dunno about you but I'm running the mist wallet on Ubuntu 16.10 64-bit I ran a test and it gave me the out put in the attached screen cap.[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq0D0.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq0D0.png)

Comment: I needed to change from Morden to Ropsten testnetwork

Comment: Sometimes Ethereum Wallet or Mist hangs up unexpectedly. Restarting usually helps, although it is kind of mind grinding restart now and then...